# Cannot print out array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm doing something with canvas and I need to process some text that users type in. My problem is, I want to print out the content of the 'w' array each time the for loop runs, but I always get undefined. Can anyone tell me why?

```js
var text = 'Test 123';
var post = text.split('');
var words = [];

function wrapText() {
  var w = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
    if (/[a-zA-z]/.test(post[i])) {
      if (/[^a-zA-z]/.test(post[i - 1]) && /[^a-zA-Z]/.test(post[i + 1])) {

        words[w] = post[i];
        w++;

      } else {
        var com = words[w];

        if (typeof com === 'undefined') {
          com = '';
        }

        words[w] = com + post[i];

        if (/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(post[i + 1])) {
          w++;
        }
      }
    } else {
      words[w] = post[i];
      w++;
    }
  }

  console.log('result:', words[w]);
}

wrapText();
```

Comment: I think you need to call the function `wraptext();` And you're missing a `}` on your code

Comment: did you notice you are increasing the w by `1` after pushing element? so if you added last nth element now w is on n+1 which is not in your `word` array. and yes @JeremiahCabigting is right one closing `}` is missing

Comment: @JeremiahCabigting Sorry, I will be careful next time when I capture the code

Comment: @DeepakSharma Thanks! This problem has confused me  for a week.

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote a short description about what the code should do and what `words[w]` should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `words`, instead of `words[w]` in the console

```
console.log('result:', words);
```

`w` will be `length of the array +1` so it will be undefined. If you want to print total array use words.

Here is the output

```js
var text = 'Test 123';
var post = text.split('');
var words = [];

function wrapText() {
  var w = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
    if (/[a-zA-z]/.test(post[i])) {
      if (/[^a-zA-z]/.test(post[i - 1]) && /[^a-zA-Z]/.test(post[i + 1])) {

        words[w] = post[i];
        w++;

      } else {
        var com = words[w];

        if (typeof com === 'undefined') {
          com = '';
        }

        words[w] = com + post[i];

        if (/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(post[i + 1])) {
          w++;
        }
      }
    } else {
      words[w] = post[i];
      w++;
    }
  }

  console.log('result:', words);
}

wrapText();
```